# How can I optimize my r code to go faster

Tags: r

I'm working with two data frames A and B , so suppose in column 1 of df A i have clients ID's and in column 2 every purchase made by that client, a 800k by 2 df. In the other hand i have df B with column 1 clients ID's and column 2 a  single purchase made by the client, a 300k by 2 df. Example
A =

| ID | Purchases |
| --- | --- |
| 362 | shoes;shirt;... |
| 363 | pants;pants;... |

B=

| ID | Purchase |
| --- | --- |
| 362 | shoes |
| 362 | shirt |
| 363 | pants |
| 363 | pants |

If i want to concatenate each client purchase in column 2 of df A i have to do a 2 for loop to search for every id in df A ,every purchase in df B.

The sizes are 300k and 800k. I´ve transformed the df´s into lists to speed up mi code but it still very slow, it took 4459.75 elapsed , 3900.95 in user and 541.37 in system. Is there better data structures to use? To concatenate I'm using the paste function.

Here's the code :

```
for (i in 1:800000){
    for(j in 1:300000){
        if(A$ID[i]==B$ID[j]) A$purchases[i]= paste(A$purchases[i],B$purchase[j],sep=";")
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code that you're using?

Comment: ... and unambiguous representative sample data (i.e., `dput(head(x))`), please. I for one will not spend time trying to optimize code I haven't with data I don't know.

Comment: Just added the code

Comment: Your code is not helpful (at the moment) for two reasons: (1) we don't know what `A` and `B` are; and (2) your `if` statement *does nothing*, it pastes something that is assigned nowhere.

Comment: Here's how to optimize stack overflow time-to-answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It kind of looks like you're trying to do a join. Try looking into `inner_join`, `left_join`, etc. from the `dplyr` package.

Comment: Try merging: ``library(dplyr);merge(x = A, y = B, by = "ID", all.x = T) %>% mutate(.,purchases = paste(purchases.x,purchases.y,sep=";"))``

Comment: Does `A$Purchases` require uniqueness? That is, for ID 362, should the results be `"shoes;shirt;...;shoes;shirt"`? It is not clear in your question.

Comment: doesn't require uniqueness @r2evans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are a few things to mention here.

1. Your operation on the face of it is a two-*step* (no loops required): take your `B`, summarize into one-row-per-user (collapse the strings into one), then join and append on `A`'s data. Both of those are simple steps on their own, so we'll walk through the basics of this.
2. If you want to ensure uniqueness in `A`, we need to re-process every line. While one might go with regexes (with the *assumption* that a semicolon will *never* appear in real data), I think that can get a little expensive in the long run. (Granted, nowhere near as expensive as a double-`for`-loop, nothing I suggest will be within an order of magnitude of that slow.) Another option is to convert `Purchases` into a list-column, for which we can do simpler (less-slow) operations for set-membership, etc.

On the face of it, try this:

```r
library(dplyr)
B %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(NewPurchases = paste(Purchase, collapse = ";"))
# # A tibble: 1 x 2
#      ID NewPurchases
#   <int> <chr>       
# 1   362 shoes;shirt
```

this we can join back onto `A`, concatenate, and ...

```r
B %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(NewPurchases = paste(Purchase, collapse = ";")) %>%
  full_join(A, ., by = "ID") %>%
  mutate(Purchases = paste(na.omit(c(Purchases, NewPurchases)), collapse = ";")) %>%
  select(-NewPurchases)
#    ID                   Purchases
# 1 362 shoes;shirt;...;shoes;shirt
```

I think that list-columns are still a better way to go, for two reasons:

1. No need to worry about escaping `;` (if ever present), the contents of that column on any single row is a vector of `character`, 0 or more, so each "purchase" is its own element within the vector;
2. We can use set-membership or uniqueness or similar when combining. This also includes tabulating (summarizing) by purchase item.

Let's first convert `A$Purchases` to a list-column:

```r
A <- mutate(A, Purchases = strsplit(Purchases, ";"))
A
#    ID         Purchases
# 1 362 shoes, shirt, ...
str(A)
# 'data.frame': 1 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ ID       : int 362
#  $ Purchases:List of 1
#   ..$ : chr  "shoes" "shirt" "..."
```

From here, the revised workflow to join in `B` data:

```r
newA <- B %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(NewPurchases = list(Purchase)) %>%
  full_join(A, ., by = "ID") %>%
  mutate(Purchases = Map(c, Purchases, NewPurchases)) %>%
  ### or, if you want to guarantee uniqueness
  # mutate(Purchases = Map(function(a, b) unique(c(a, b)), Purchases, NewPurchases)) %>%
  select(-NewPurchases)
newA
#    ID                              Purchases
# 1 362 shoes, shirt, ..., shoes, shirt, pants
```

From here, tabulating purchases can be as easy as:

```r
table(unlist(newA$Purchases))
#   ... pants shirt shoes 
#     1     1     2     2
```

or per-`ID` with

```r
xtabs(~ ID + Purchases, data = tidyr::unnest(newA, Purchases))
#      Purchases
# ID    ... pants shirt shoes
#   362   1     1     2     2
```